# Use terminal to open a file by Excel on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, shell, command-line, terminal

Now, in MacOS terminal: I can open a file by Sublime Text just by running:

```bash
subl [path]
```

Can I do something of the kind when using `Excel`?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Open a file by default application, just

```bash
open [path]
```

If want to change, can use

```bash
open -a [app-path] [file-path]
```

From the `man open` page (more info on the `-a` option):

```
DESCRIPTION
     The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), 
     just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name
     is specified, the default application as determined via LaunchServices is 
     used to open the specified files.

     If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.

     You can specify one or more file names (or pathnames), 
     which are interpreted relative to the shell or Terminal window's current 
     working directory. 
     For example, the following command would 
     open all Word files in the current working
     directory:

     open *.doc

     Opened applications inherit environment variables just 
     as if you had launched the application directly through its full path.  
     This behavior was also present in Tiger.

     The options are as follows:

     -a application
         Specifies the application to use for opening the file
```

Comment: Note that you need to change the file association for some filename endings like '*.tsv'.

Comment: Thanks for this.
I just added this to my .zshrc file


    `alias excel='open -a /Applications/Microsoft\ Excel.app'`

and now I can open a file with` 'excel [filename]'`.